# How can customize my HTML if it is inside a JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

here's my `profile.js`

```
profileContainer.innerHTML = 
`
<div class="col-md-12">
    <section class="jumbotron my-5">

        <h3 class="text-center">First Name: ${data.firstName}</h3>
        <h3 class="text-center">Last Name: ${data.lastName}</h3>
        <h3 class="text-center">Email: ${data.email}</h3>
        <h3 class="text-center">Contact Number: ${data.mobileNo}</h3>
        <h3 class="mt-5">Class History</h3>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> Course Name </th>
                    <th> Enrolled On </th>
                    <th> Status </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="coursesContainer"></tbody>
            </table> 
        </section>
    </div>
`
```

and this is my `profile.html`

```
<main class="container my-5">
    <div id="profileContainer" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <section class="jumbotron text-center my-5">        
                <h2 class="my-5"><span class="spinner-border text-primary"></span> Fetching User 
               Details...</h2>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end row -->
</main>
```

This is the expected output:
[profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2liD.png)

I tried changing the background color of the profile from gray to another color, but targeting the `profileContainer` through `style.css` only changes color of the outer border.. please help

Comment: Try using your browser's dev tools to see exactly what CSS is being applied to what elements.

Comment: I didn't think of that, will try it though, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to update the whole page i.e  overwrite the whole html code you need to add a button that initiates the page update event or you wont see any user interaction .

under  tag add a button

```html
<main class="container my-5">
    <div id="profileContainer" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <section class="jumbotron text-center my-5">        
                <h2 class="my-5"><span class="spinner-border text-primary"></span> Fetching User 
               Details...</h2>
        <button onclick="myfunction()">click me</button>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end row -->
</main>
```

your JS code should be updated as

```js
function myfunction() {
document.getElementById("profileContainer").innerHTML="<div class="col-md-12">
<section class="jumbotron my-5">
  <h3 class="text-center">First Name: ${data.firstName}</h3>
    <h3 class="text-center">Last Name: ${data.lastName}</h3>
    <h3 class="text-center">Email: ${data.email}</h3>
    <h3 class="text-center">Contact Number: ${data.mobileNo}</h3>
    <h3 class="mt-5">Class History</h3>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Course Name </th>
                <th> Enrolled On </th>
                <th> Status </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="coursesContainer"></tbody>
        </table> 
    </section>
</div>" ;  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target classes or IDs specified within JS the same way you would any other HTML. Depending on the specific element on the page you're trying to style, you could try targeting `.jumbotron`

Without seeing what CSS already exists to know what elements styling is currently being applied to (i.e., which class the gray background and border radius are actually tied to), it's hard to provide specifics.

Answer (score 1):

What basically we do is that we provide an id or class to the element. Try to do that and then code the css in the stylesheet. This is the easy and foremost way to get out of this rid.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the HTML element that you want to change by giving it an ID and select by using the JavaScript property which is `getelementbyid`, and changing its inner HTML by using the `innerhtml` property.

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. It should be `getElementById` and `innerHTML`. Also, `getElementById` is a method of the `document` object. You may want to make that clearer in your answer.